# Recorrer JSON con libreria python requests

Tags: json, python-requests

en mi ejemplo quiero acceder a todos los albums que tiene coldplay. este es el json.
Tengo entendido que con la libreria requests lo transformo a un diccionario pero no puedo acceder a los albunes sino que me devuelve el valor de cada posicion en el elemento topalbums
https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c8de55785bbb400cb34c62d519e2962d

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist=coldplay&api_key=a31007b9178e35854f9fa22039cb7362&format=json')
musica_dict = json.loads(r.text)

print type(musica_dict)

for item in musica_dict:
    for album in item:
        print album
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu objeto **musica_dict** es un diccionario, contiene una llave **topalbums**, y si accedes a **musica_dict['topalbums']** también es un diccionario que tiene dos llaves, **album y @attr**.

**musica_dict['topalbums']['album']** es una lista (que puedes iterar), cada elemento de esta lista es un diccionario que contiene las llaves **'name', 'playcount', 'mbid', 'url', 'artist', 'image'**.

Entonces para imprimir la información seria de la siguiente manera:

```
for i in musica_dict['topalbums']['album']:
    print "Album: {}\nURL: {}".format(i['name'], i['url'])
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/216856/setear-un-par%C3%A1metro-de-un-formulario-a-una-url-y-obtener-sus-valores-en-la-vista  podrias mirar esta pregunta por favor