# Setear un parámetro de un formulario a una url y obtener sus valores en la vista

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, flask, python-requests

quiero poder buscar en un campo un artista/banda de la api lastfm utilizando flask y request.
Y tengo problemas en la sintaxis y/o logica pero no se como corregirlos.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/vista', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
  params = {
    'api_key': '5c1016ab26ab5b2f6ad21c3d873785bc',
    'format' : 'json',
    'artist': request.args.get('artista')
  }
  r = requests.get(
      'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums',
      params=params)

  return render_template('vista.html',
               albums=r.json()['topalbums']['album'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run (host = '127.0.0.1', port = 5000, threaded=True)





   <form action="/buscador.py">
      Artista: <input type="search" name="artista"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="buscar">
    </form>
```

[image: Debug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se entiende exactamente cuál es tu problema, pero hay varios errores en tu código:

1. La `api_key` ha de ser una cadena que contenga sólo dígitos hexadecimales, por tanto las llaves al principio y al final sobran.
2. El campo `artist` debería estar mejor dentro de los parámetros enviados, y no dentro de la URL, pues ¿y si el nombre del artista contiene espacios o caractreres no-ascii? Debe ser recodificado adecuadamente para que sea una URL válida. `requests` se ocupa de ello si se lo pasas en `params`, pero no si lo metes en la URL con una mera concatenación.
3. Por defecto la API de last.fm te devuelve los resultados en XML. Tu código parece asumir que la respuesta viene en JSON, por lo que `json.loads()` romperá. Para que la respuesta venga en JSON debes añadir a `params` un campo `format` con valor `"json"`.
4. El JSON retornado, en su campo `['topalbums']['album']` lo que tiene es una lista (¡puede tener 50 elementos!). Si quieres obtener sólo el primero de ellos necesitas poner `[0]` para seleccionarlo (y después obtener su `['name']`. No queda muy claro si tu vista (template) espera solo un álbum o una lista de ellos, pero en todo caso lo de `['topalbums']['album']['name']` fallaría.

Supongamos que el template espera una lista de albums y que él mismo se ocupa de acceder al título usando un bucle y `album.name` o similar. Este sería entonces el código flask:

```
@app.route('/vista', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
  params = {
    'api_key': '5c1016ab26ab5b2f6ad21c3d873785bc',
    'format' : 'json',
    'artist': request.args.get('artista')
  }
  r = requests.get(
      'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums',
      params=params)

  return render_template('vista.html', 
               albums=r.json()['topalbums']['album'])
```

**Nota**. Para servir la petición de tus clientes estás haciendo que Flask haga a su vez otra petición web. Esta petición requiere un tiempo, durante el cual tu cliente estará esperando la respuesta. Pero lo que es peor, ya que Flask es mono-proceso y mono-hilo, el servidor completo quedará bloqueado hasta que `requests` retorne el resultado, impidiéndole servir a más clientes. Puede estar bien para pruebas, pero para producción deberías desplegar Flask mediante `gunicorn`, por ejemplo, para soportar concurrencia (mientras un cliente está esperando su respuesta, el servidor puede ir atendiendo a otros).

### Actualización

El código anterior, al usar `request.args.get('artista')` para recuperar del formulario el artista a buscar, está implícitamente esperando que ese artista le llegue como parte de la URL (es decir, que le venga en una petición así: `GET /vista?artista=Coldplay` por ejemplo).

Sin embargo un formulario HTML por defecto efectúa una petición `POST` y codifica los parámetros del formulario de una forma especial como parte del cuerpo del POST y no en la URL, por lo que el código anterior no funcionará.

Una forma sencilla de arreglarlo es decirle al navegador que el formulario debe hacer una petición `GET` en vez de POST. Así:

```html
<form action="/buscador.py" method="GET">
  Artista: <input type="search" name="artista"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="buscar">
</form>
```

Otra posibilidad es dejar el FORM como estaba (por tanto usará POST), y cambiar la parte Flask para que obtenga el nombre del artista de esta otra forma:

```python
  params = {
    ...
    'artist': request.form['artista']
  }
```

### Segunda actualización

Ya que el usuario quiere usar una misma vista para mostrar tanto el FORM como los resultados del mismo (dato que no había entendido yo correctamente), resulta que la misma ruta puede llevar o no el parámetro `artista`, según haya sido invocado como un mero `GET /` o en respuesta al submit del FORM.

Es necesario distinguir estos casos en el código para evitar la petición a la API de last.fm si no hay `artista` que buscar.

El código sería así:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/vista')
def homepage():
  artista = request.args.get('artista')

  # Si no tenemos artista, devolvemos el template que tiene
  # el form y una lista vacía de resultados
  if not artista:
    return render_template('vista.html', albums=[])

  # Si tenemos artista, es como antes
  params = {
    'api_key': '5c1016ab26ab5b2f6ad21c3d873785bc',
    'format' : 'json',
    'artist': artista
  }
  r = requests.get(
      'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums',
      params=params)

  return render_template('vista.html', 
               albums=r.json()['topalbums']['album'])
```

El FORM debe hacer un GET a la ruta `/vista`, por tanto debe ser así:

```html
   <form action="/vista" method="GET">
      Artista: <input type="search" name="artista"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="buscar">
    </form>
```

Comment: no sabia como expresar mi duda pero en el template me gustaria mostrar una lista albums para despues asociarle  una imagen a cada uno, deberia iterar eso en la vista ,no?

Comment: Disculpa con el script compartiste sale excepcion de key error y topalbums  esa key del array https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=56ee251015d646f086be33bc2daf29b0     Cual es el error?

Comment: Ahora que me fijo, intentas recuperar el artista del formulario mediante `request.args.get('artista')`, pero el formulario HTML que has mostrado no ha puesto `method="GET"`, con lo que por defecto te estará enviando los argumentos en el cuerpo del POST y no en la URL, por lo que para extraerlos con Flask tienes que usar `request.form['artista']` (o poner `method="GET"` en el FORM).

Comment: Podrias poner el form en la respuesta es que me confundi un poco con lo ultimo que dijiste ya artist lo pasabas asi 'artist': request.args.get('artista')

Comment: @Diego He actualizado la pregunta. Mira a ver si ahora te queda más claro

Comment: Ahí agregue la excepción que me sigue apareciendo y cambien el post por un get pero aun sigue saliendo la misma excepción cuando entro a la url, dejo captura de estructura del proyecto y keyerror

Comment: @Diego Lo que has añadido en la pregunta no es de mucha ayuda, pues sólo nos dice que el json retornado por la API no tiene el campo `"topalbums"`, pero no sabemos por qué. Por suerte, ya que estás ejecutando flask en modo debug, puedes usar el propio navegador web para indagar más. Verás que en el stacktrace que te muestra hay un icono de una terminal junto a cada error. Pulsa en el último y entras en un interprete que te permite examinar las variables de tu servidor flask. Mira el valor de `r.status_code`, el de `r.json()` y el de `params`, a ver si de ahi sacamos más pistas.

Comment: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist=coldplay&api_key=0fdb3dd25872afb7b2850d7dfe0a20dc&format=json   si tiene el campo "topalbums"

Comment: ahi agregue la vista del debug, me devuelve un 200 pero cuando le doy run no me muestra el formulario directamente me muestra la excepcion de key error, sera que en 'artist': request.args.get('artista') esta parte esta mal?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86248/discussion-between-abulafia-and-diego).